# Azure AD B2C: Send Registration Source to CRM profile from ADB2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

we are facing issue with finding the source of registration of user in Azure AD B2C.

We are looking for solution to update the CRM from AD B2C the source of registration of user (Local, Google or Apple)

Regards

we are not able to get any solution

Comment: You should look at the `identities` of the User objects when querying through Graph API. Documentation of user properties: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties. The `issuer` property there should contain what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this multiple ways, and the best solution will depend on your circumstances.

1. When a user is created for the first time, the JWT sent to the application can include claims `newUser` and `authenticationSource`, from this information your application can update the CRM.
2. On a scheduled task, such as an azure function, you could poll for newly created users (you can limit the results for anyone created after *x* date/time and the function updates the CRM. See [Getting a user with specific properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-3-use-select-to-retrieve-specific-properties-of-a-user) and [Graph API filter parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/filter-query-parameter?tabs=http#syntax-for-using-the-filter-odata-query-parameter) - akin to what @juunas mentioned.
3. Probably the most common option is to call an API during the flow when the user signs-up using the [REST API technical profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/restful-technical-profile). This would allow you to call an API which handles adding/updating the CRM as appropriate. [Implementation example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policies-series-call-rest-api)